# Storing Images in database with BLOB type

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, file, blob

I have a question. How to save the file in the database? I use Spring Boot for backend language and PostgreSQL database. I have a User entity, and there is "avatar" field:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "avatar", columnDefinition="BLOB")
private byte[] avatar;

@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public byte[] getAvatar() {
   return avatar;
}
public void setAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
   this.avatar = avatar;
}
```

When I first register a user, avatar is got to null and when I save my user to DB I get an error (InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException) and this message:
**ERROR: column "avatar" is of type jsonb but expression is of type oid

Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 173**

What can I do to solve this issue?
How does Spring solves this problem and saves files in DB?
What is the best practice?

Comment: Looks like the DB scheme has type *jsonb*. What do you see with `\d` in db console

Comment: I see jsonb format

Comment: That's why you can't write a blob into it.

Comment: And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the community project [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  This project gives you a Spring Data-like API and development approach for content.  It is to unstructured data (documents, images, videos, etc), what Spring Data is to structured data.  You could add it with something like the following:-

> pom.xml (Spring Boot starters also available)

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>          
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.M10</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.M10</version>
   </dependency>
```

> Configuration

```
@Configuration
// enables Java API 
@EnableJpaStores
// enables REST API 
@Import("org.springframework.content.rest.config.RestConfiguration.class") 
public class ContentConfig {

   // specify the resource specific to your database
   @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-drop-postgresql.sql")
   private ClasspathResource dropBlobTables;

   // specify the resource specific to your database
   @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-postgresql.sql")
   private ClasspathResource createBlobTables;

   @Bean
   DataSourceInitializer datasourceInitializer() {
     ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator =
            new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

     databasePopulator.addScript(dropBlobTables);
     databasePopulator.addScript(createBlobTables);
     databasePopulator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);

     DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
     initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
     initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);

     return initializer;
   }
}
```

> NB: this configuration is not needed if you use the relevant Spring Boot starter.

To associate content, add Spring Content annotations to your User entity.

> User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

   ...

   // replace @Lob/byte array field with:

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;
    
   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;
    
   @MimeType
   private String mimeType;
```

Create a avatar "store" for your images:

> AvatarStore.java

```
public interface AvatarStore extends ContentStore<User, String> {
}
```

This is all you need to create REST endpoints @ `/users/{userId}` that respond to content types.  When your application starts, Spring Content will look at your dependencies (seeing Spring Content JPA/REST), look at your `AvatarStore` interface and inject an implementation of that interface for JPA.  It will also inject a `@Controller` that forwards http requests to that implementation.  This saves you having to implement any of this yourself.

So...

`curl -X POST /users/{userId} -F 'file=@path/to/local/file.jpg'`

will store the avatar `path/to/local/file.jpg` in the database and associate it with the User entity whose id is `userId`.

`curl /users/{usersId} -H 'Accept: image/jpg'`

will fetch it again and so on...supports full CRUD (and video streaming too BTW)

There getting started guides and videos [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  The  reference guide for Spring Content JPA is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/jpa-index.html).

HTH

Comment: Is there any other way to do this, because if I select this variant I will change a lot of code.